# vite removes format import "import foo from "./assets/foo.svg?component"

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vite

I use vite-svg-loader + vue + ts, but if I try to import any svg into vue component , the import is automatically deleted because It is allegedly not used

I use WebStorm and i checked my setting (eslint) but they turned off and i don't what is problem

```js
My vite-config

import {defineConfig} from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

import svgLoader from 'vite-svg-loader'

export default defineConfig({
    base: "./",
    plugins: [vue(), svgLoader()]
})
```

```js
My vue component, but if I save file, import deleted
<template>

  <IconNavMain/>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import IconNavMain from "./assets/vue.svg?component"
</script>
```

Comment: By posting text as images, you are inviting downvotes and a lack of participation. Please fix this for a better experience on SO.

Answer (score 0):

It's just WebStorm bug ,if you need fix it, just turned off eslint rules about not using imports

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).